# Returning objects of different types from Neo4j with Spring Data?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Does anyone know how to return a collection of different objects mapped from Neo4j nodes within a Spring-Data-Neo4j graph repository?

If I have a repository like this:

```
interface JunctionGraph extends GraphRepository<Junction>, SpatialRepository<Junction> {
    @Query("MATCH (a) WHERE a.name={0} RETURN a")
    Collection<Object> findAllWithName(String name)
}
```

what like to see is **findAllWithName** returning a list of all the different mapped objects that have the specified name. Instead I just get a collect of **Node**s. How do I persuade SDN to map all the nodes into the right object type?

Comment: Good question you could instead have it return a Result<Object>, not 100% that that works, alternatively there is a method on Neo4jTemplate that allows you to project it to the stored Java type. `template.createEntityFromStoredType(node,null)`